# Xcode 4 + 5 compatible code using tabBar setTranslucent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm trying to use `[tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];` in my app for iOS7.
However, I want the code to compile using xcode 4.

So I check the iOS version at runtime

```
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (ver >= 7.0) {
```

using `[tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];` in Xcode 4 produces the error..

**No visible @interface for 'UITabBar' declares the selector 'setTranslucent:'**

Because setTanslucent isn't available in iOS6.

I've had many attempts but either the code doesn't run or causes an error...

```
  //UITabBar *tabBarr = [tabBarController tabBar];
    //if ([tabBarr respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setTranslucent")]) {
    //    [tabBarr setValue:NO forKey:@"setTranslucent"];
    //}

    //if ([tabBarr respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)]) {
    //    [tabBarr setTranslucent:NO];
    //}

   // tabBarController.tabBar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //if ([tabBarr respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)]) {
    //if ([[tabBarController.tabBar class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)]) {
        //[tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
        //[tabBarController.tabBar setBool:NO forKey:@"setTranslucent"];
     //   [tabBarController.tabBar setValue:NO forKey:@"setTranslucent:"];
    //}
```

I'm not sure what else to try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a category and define the `property` again

```
@interface UITabBar (OldSDKCompatibility)
@property(nonatomic,getter=isTranslucent) BOOL translucent;
@end
```

Comment: So if compile with Xcode 4 and my app is ran on iOS 7, it would use that ?

Comment: As long as you make sure, that this `@property` is only used on iOS7 then you should be fine. The only thing this category does, is telling the compiler to shut up. While, those warnings are there for a reason, your case is special. Still, test this before shipping.

Answer (score 1):

I define macros instead an use these:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Use like:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) { ... )
```

See if the issue is with your version check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will still cause the compiler error. Hmmm, maybe I just need to wrap that line with compiler ignore warning conditions.

Comment: Ahhh I can't add a compiler warning condition as it's an error :(

Comment: Good question, I was evaluating this option earlier and I can't find a reason. I thought that I may have issues in the validation process, but theses were small issues.

Comment: Seems like a good time to make the move. Keep a backup of your Xcode4 config for the project

Comment: I am guessing you are using some form of repo for this, I would back that up including the relevant xcode project configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: This problem is you can't use functionality not in the sdk. Therefore use Xcode 4 and don't use that code or use Xcode 5.